# How can I paste commands on Minecraft Command Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, macos

So I have a mac computer but i plugged in a windows keyboard in my mac. I am still trying to figure out how to paste commands into a command block. So how can I paste a command?

Comment: Tried `CTRL`+`V`? I'd guess that you're posting here because that's not working, but just making sure.

Comment: The Mac commands for copy/paste are `⌘` + `C` and `⌘` + `V`. Obviously, the Windows keyboard has no `⌘` key, but usually the windows key is mapped to `⌘`, so try `win` + `C` and `win` + `V`.

Comment: Ok and I did try CTRL+V so I will try win+c and win+v

Answer (score 3):

This actually depends on what version you're using. Since there's no right-click function in the command block menu, you have to use keyboard shortcuts; however, different versions use different shortcuts. Minecraft 1.7.10 and earlier were all made using the shortcuts for Windows and other systems, so if you're using one of those older versions you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. This gets confusing, because other applications still use <kbd>⌘</kbd> on Mac. However, if you're using any version of 1.8 or later, you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, like the other applications on Mac do.

**TL;DR** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> if you're using 1.8 or higher, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> if you're on 1.7.10 or lower

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after highlighting the command you want to use to copy it, and then go into the command block and use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it.

Comment: Do you think you could improve your formatting? (Such as using the <kbd> tags?)