# Why can't I copy paste into minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to get a custom command, but when I copy it, ctrl+v doesn't work! I am using version 1.8.3. Help me please!

Comment: What are you trying to copy it into?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I paste commands on Minecraft Command Blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219779/how-can-i-paste-commands-on-minecraft-command-blocks)

Comment: @pppery The other question seems to specify minecraft running on a mac. This may or may not be true in this case. This question could use some more info. What system/OS is it running on? Where is the command copied from? What are you trying to copy? (it might be too long to fit...)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any shortcut programs running on your computer? (Auto-hotkey, etc)
Those can mess with keyboard shortcuts in other applications. Other than that, I can only suggest that you update your Minecraft, or double-check that you actually *copied* the command in the first place.